# Apport: bug unreportable due to truncated core dump

Tags: 19.04, apport

Sometimes after logging in I get a message saying:

> Sorry, Ubuntu 19.04 has experienced an internal error.
>
> Send problem report to the developers?

I always click `Send`, but don't think it really works for me. If I click `Show Details` before that, [I see](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eapport-hackers/apport/trunk/view/head:/apport/report.py#L743):

> ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
> UnreportableReason: Invalid core dump: BFD: warning: /tmp/apport_core_3znvp3mb is truncated: expected core file size >= 2981888, found: 61440

The information seems to come from `/var/crash/_usr_bin_dbus-daemon.1000.crash`.
I saw [a similar discussion on a mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5514388.html) and I checked:

- `/var/log/apport.log` is empty
- `/tmp` is not full (has `6.8G` available)
- `ulimit -c` is `0`

What could be cause for the truncated core dump? How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm having a what it seems the same issue every login with Albert v0.17.2 on 20.04